# What is the time complexity of the algorithm below?

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

I just want to have confirmation of the time complexity of the algorithm below.

**EDIT**: in what follows, we do not assume that the optimal data structures are being used. However, feel free to propose solutions that use such structures (clearly mentioning what data structures are used and what beneficial impact they have on complexity).

[image]

**Notation**: in what follows n=|V|, m=|E|, and avg_neigh denotes the average number of neighbors of any given node in the graph.

**Assumption**: the graph is unweighted, undirected, and we have its adjacency list representation loaded in memory (a list of lists containing the neighbors of each vertex).

Here is what we have so far:

**Line 1**: computing the degrees is O(n), as it simply involves getting the length of each sublist in the adjacency list representation, i.e., performing n O(1) operations.

**Line 3**: finding the lowest value requires checking all values, which is O(n). Since this is nested in the while loop which visits all nodes once, it becomes O(n^2).

**Lines 6-7**: removing vertex v is O(avg_neigh^2) as we know the neighbors of v from the adjacency list representation and removing v from each of the neighbors' sublists is O(avg_neigh). Lines 6-7 are nested in the while loop, so it becomes O(n * avg_neigh^2).

**Line 9**: it is O(1), because it simply involves getting the length of one list. It is nested in the for loop and while loop so it becomes O(n * avg_neigh).

**Summary**: the total complexity is  O(n) + O(n^2) + O(n * avg_neigh^2) + O(n * avg_neigh) = O(n^2).

**Note 1**: if the length of each sublist is not available (e.g., because the adjacency list cannot be loaded in memory), computing the degrees in line 1 is O(n * avg_neigh), as each list features avg_neigh elements on average and there are n sublists. And line 9, the total complexity becomes O(n * avg_neigh^2).

**Note 2**: if the graph is weighted, we can store the edge weights in the adjacency list representation. However, getting the degrees in line 1 requires summing over each sublist and is now O(n * avg_neigh) if the adjacency list is loaded in RAM and O(n * avg_neigh^2) else. Similarly, line 9 becomes O(n * avg_neigh^2) or O(n * avg_neigh^3).

Comment: Is there any assumption of how `p` is implemented? For example, could it be a [max-heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), or is it just an array?

Comment: Why in the Summary you conclude that a sum of elements of those classes is in O(n^2)? Isn't the avg_neigh close to n in the worst case, giving that that the class O(n*avg_neigh^2) is the same as the class O(n^3)?

Comment: you've made excellent points, thank you. I was assuming p to be a simple dictionary, but indeed some other data structures might be more efficient. In the worst case, I completely agree that we get close to O(n^3).

Comment: As @conditionalMethod notes, the running time depends on which data structures are chosen. Careful choices lead to an O(|V| + |E|)-time algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I have edited my question to reflect that. Could you please take the time to write an answer explaining how you reach O(|V| + |E|)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an algorithm that (1) is recognizable as an implementation of Algorithm 1 and (2) runs in time O(|E| + |V|).

First, let's consider the essence of Algorithm 1. Until the graph is empty, do the following: record the priority of the node with the lowest priority as the core number of that node, and delete that node. The priority of a node is defined dynamically as the maximum over (1) its degree in the residual graph and (2) the core numbers of its deleted neighbors. Observe that the priority of a node never increases, since its degree never increases, and a higher-priority neighbor would not be deleted first. Also, priorities always decrease by exactly one in each outer loop iteration.

The data structure support sufficient to achieve O(|E| + |V|) time splits nicely into

1. A graph that, starting from the initial graph (initialization time O(|E| + |V|)), supports

   - Deleting a node (O(degree + 1), summing to O(|E| + |V|) over all nodes),
   - Getting the residual degree of a node (O(1)).
2. A priority queue that, starting from the initial degrees (initialization time O(|V|)), supports

   - Popping the minimum priority element (O(1) amortized),
   - Decreasing the priority of an element by one (O(1)), never less than zero.

A suitable graph implementation uses doubly linked adjacency lists. Each undirected edge has two corresponding list nodes, which are linked to each other in addition to the previous/next nodes originating from the same vertex. Degrees can be stored in a hash table. It turns out we only need the residual degrees to implement this algorithm, so don't bother storing the residual graph.

Since the priorities are numbers between 0 and |V| - 1, a [bucket queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_queue) works very nicely. This implementation consists of a |V|-element vector of doubly linked lists, where the list at index p contains the elements of priority p. We also track a lower bound on the minimum priority of an element in the queue. To find the minimum priority element, we examine the lists in order starting from this bound. In the worst case, this costs O(|V|), but if we credit the algorithm whenever it increases the bound and debit it whenever the bound decreases, we obtain an amortization scheme that offsets the variable cost of this scanning.

Answer (score 2):

If choosing a data structure that can support efficient lookup of min value and efficient deletions (such as [self balancing binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) or [min heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap)), this can be done in `O(|E|log|V|)`.

- Creating the data structure in line 1 is done in `O(|V|)` or
  `O(|V|log|V|)`.
- The loop goes exactly once over each node `v` in `V`.
- For each such node, it needs to peek the min value, and adjust the DS so you can peek at the next min efficiently next iteration. `O(log|V|)` is required for that (otherwise, you could do heap sort in `o(nlogn)` - note [little o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) here).
- Getting `neighbors`, and removing items from `V` and `E` could be done in `O(|neighbors|)` using efficient set implementation, such as a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Since each edge and node is chosen exactly once for this step, it sums over all iterations in `O(|V| + |E|)`.
- The for loop over `neighbors`, again, sums to `O(|E|)`, thanks to the fact that each edge is counted exactly once here.
- In this loop, however, you might need to update `p`, and such an update costs `O(log|V|)`, so this sums to `O(|E|log|V|)`

This sums in `O(|V|log|V| + |E|log|V|)`. Assuming the graph is not very sparse (`|E|` is in `Omega(|V|`) - this is `O(|E|log|V|)`.

Comment: could the person who downvoted explain the reason for the downvote?